# What's the difference between v3 and v4 of the Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

A new version of the [Sheets API (v4)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) is now available. How is this different than the [existing version (v3)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) that has been available for years?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of differences, including:

- Protocol: v3 is built on the older GData platform and uses XML/ATOM over HTTP, while v4 is built on the newer Google APIs platform and uses JSON over HTTP.
- Client Libraries: v3 uses the older GData client libraries, which are only
  available for a handful of programming languages, while v4 uses the newer Google APIs client
  libraries which are [available for 9 languages](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/libraries).
- Features: While v3 could only read and write spreadsheet cell values, v4
  provides access to nearly every spreadsheet feature, including charts, pivot
  tables, and filter views.
- Formatting: v3 could only write the value of the cells, but v4 provides 
  complete access to cell formatting. You can set colors, text styles, and even
  add conditional formatting.

Information on how to upgrade to v4 is available in the 
[migration guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration).

Comment: @ Eric Koleda. Is v4 faster than v3 when it comes to writing and reading data to and from sheets?